# Elasticsearch "node.attr.{attribute}" not picked up by cluster node(s)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a six node ES-cluster where I want to categorize them by type using the `node.attr.box_type: hot` or `node.attr.box_type: warm` approach. In my elasticsearch.yml file (for each node) I have, among other things, a line reading `node.attr.box_type: hot`, but when I, after a restart, send a `GET _cat/nodeattrs?v` OR `GET _nodes/box_type:hot` command, none of them returns any nodes from the cluster. It seems like the `node.attr.{attribute}` value is NOT picked up by ES. What am I doing wrong here?

Sorry, I forgot to mention the ES version: 6.2.3

Comment: which version of ES are you running? If ES 2.x, then you need to use `node.box_type` instead of `node.attr.box_type` which [has been introduced in ES 5.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/breaking_50_settings_changes.html#_node_attribute_settings)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the "problem". After investigating the available `systemctl` units I recognized I had restarted the wrong unit. After issuing the right `systemctl restart {unit}` the node attributes showed up correctly.